# Splitting the result in while loop

Tags: php, mysqli

Here i use a query for getting last two collision occurring dates of a licence number as follows:

```
<?php
$licence=$_POST['licence'];
$sel=mysqli_query($con,"select cdate from tblcollision where licence_number='$licence'");
while($s=mysqli_fetch_row($sel))
{
    echo $s[2];
}
?>
```

I wish to split the result in to separate fields. That means date1 in a text field and date2 in another text field. Actually i didn't get any idea. Please help me. 
 My db design is

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|    CID    |  ID  |  LICENCE_NUMBER  |   CDATE   |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|    1      |  1   |  3/4858/2012     | 2018-02-06 |
|    2      |  1   |  3/4858/2012     | 2018-03-20 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to injection attack because you are writing user-submitted data directly in your query.  You should implement mysqli prepared statements with placeholders as a matter of security.  I looks like you only have one column in your SELECT.  Please clarify your intent and code.  What exactly are `date1` and `date2`?  What is your expected result?  Let's seem some sample data.  For improved readability, please always write mysql keywords in UPPERCASE.

Comment: Example data and expected results are much appreciated. And will help others to help you.

Comment: date1 and date2????

Comment: Do you mean that you want to split the `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, `DAY()` values into separate values in your resultset?  If so, mysql has special functions for this ... and this would be a duplicate question.  We cannot answer your question until you clarify the issue.

Comment: The result is 2018-02-06 2018-03-20.  The expected result is i wish to get the two dates in two different text fields

Comment: Those values are in the two rows of the resultset that you are looping. I cannot see any reason to go to the trouble of combining the data into a single row.  Please explain your overarching design.  Perhaps you want a JOIN.  Do you know you will have a maximum of two dates per `ID`/`license_number`?  Honestly, I think you are making this job harder than it needs to be.  Please explain your project a little bit more if you feel this adjustment is necessary.

Comment: In what way does having two rows with a single date value in each not serve your purpose?

Comment: @AkhilaBhaskar You want this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3bba7/2 right?  As you loop through the two rows, you merely need to push each `cdate` value into the temporary storage array, then when you get your text field generation process, access the first entry then the second.

Comment: @AkhilaBhaskar I will ask you to continue to edit your question (considering my recommendations) and show us how you are setting up your form / text fields.  I am sure the community can guide you to a sensible solution. (I did not downvote your question.)  I believe every question deserves a resolution.  That may be: Correct Answer Acceptance, Question Closure (if offtopic/closable), or Question Retraction.  Please take steps to progress this page toward one of these outcomes.  Remember, this site is a living resource that will serve to educate thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by mickmackusa, if the query is filtered for a single licence number, there is no point to group result in the SQL statement and then explode the result in PHP. Just read the rows and make the calculation on the resulting dates.

However, in a more general way, if dealing with several licences, grouping can be done within the SQL statement. Despite the added cost of exploding the result, it will simplify the grouping process.

You need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` in your query:

```
SELECT licence_number, GROUP_CONCAT(cdate) AS Events_dates
FROM tblcollision
WHERE licence_number='$licence'
GROUP BY licence_number;
```

This will return:

```
3/4858/2012 | 2018-02-06, 2018-03-20
```

Comment: That does not do what the OP wants.  This would actually add to the complexity of outputting these values to separate fields.

Comment: i wish to echo  two dates in two different text fields for calculating the difference between two dates.

Comment: I think, i will use explode function to split the results

Comment: Then you would be writing convoluted/sloppy/hacky code.  There is no compelling reason to do what you are doing @Akhilla  Show your following block of code and I'll show you how wrong this implementation would be.

Comment: It doesn't add complexity, it prevents needing to loop through the results. As stated, just explode the dates field. Better is to do the calculation in the SQL query directly.

Comment: @mickmackusa, doing SQL calculation is way faster than looping through results. Neither transposing and grouping the array would be faster. You should up-vote my answer since what you see as convoluted/sloppy/hacky code is in fact more efficient coding.

Comment: _Way faster_  ...I don't know if you are arguing just to argue or if you don't realize what you are recommending.  Your method is unnecessarily indirect and advises more effort from the appropriately structured 1NF database table.  Why would any developer go to the trouble to convert two separate strings into a comma-separated string only to immediately ask php to call `explode()` to generate two separate strings again?  Functions are slower than language constructs.  There is no hope of an upvote on this answer from me.  This is a very basic, _how to make a SELECT_ query  -- mysql101.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have re-read all your comments and must agree with you in the specific case where you deal with a highly filtered query returning only one licence number.